# How to download numeric?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pygame, anaconda, ubuntu-13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.How can I download numeric for python 2.7.6?I need it for the python in anaconda 1.8.0.Please,can anyone help me?I need it for pygame 1.9.1

Comment: Use numpy, Its successor to Numeric. Numeric is deprecated. Replacing Numeric with NumPy in code might help you.

Answer (score 2):

What in PyGame makes you think you need Numeric?  Even on their web site it says that Numeric is dead and it's best to use NumPy.

Comment: so,how can i download numPy?

Comment: If you have installed Anaconda, you already have Numpy.